# Post with certain term and without any term

Tags: query, terms

I try to create a plugin to manage user groups with permission to view posts within group and I stopped because of query problem.

Example:
User belong to group called "Group #1" (slug: group-1). I assigned 1 post to "Group #1" and "Group #2" (1 post in 2 terms), 1 post to "Group #2". 1 post is without any group term so it should be visible to all groups because of no assignment. So in the end user should get 2 posts to display.

How to build a wp query (if it's possible) or how to create a sql query to get all post without any term and with terms assign to current user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible with the [`tax_query` parameters for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

The query is either for posts where any term `NOT EXISTS`, `OR`, for any posts where the term IDs are `IN` the provided array.

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'group',
        'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'group',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array( 23, 42 ),
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
)
```